# Same data causes R to crash when saved and re-loaded - but only if XML package intalled

Tags: xml, r

I've come across something I assume is a bug, but I'm having trouble even figuring out how to track down what's happening.

I am using an automated query to generate some XML-formatted information.  If I do the query and immediately use the XML package to parse it, it works fine.  But if I save the data, then reload it, and even so much as look at it, I crash R:

With the XML package loaded, I create a variable named r with XML data.  If I enter `r[[1]]` at this point I get back

```
<pointer: (nil)>
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLInternalElementNode" "XMLInternalNode"        "XMLAbstractNode"
```

However, if I do

```
save(r,"datafilename.RData")
load("datafilename.RData")
```

then it loads fine up until I enter `r[[1]]` again, at which point what happens depends on whether the XML package is still loaded up.  If it is not, then I get the same result as above; if it is, I get a pop-up stating that R has encountered a fatal error and needs to close.

I have regenerated the same dataset as well as a new and smaller test dataset from the same source a dozen times - this is completely and utterly reproducible / happens every time.  I don't understand the options on "save" very well, but I've tried saving as binary and ascii, and with compress left to its default or set to FALSE, and these do not make any difference.  At this point, I'm having trouble figuring out how to track down the problem any further.

Any ideas, for example, what changes when something is saved and reloaded?  Are there further ways I could be controlling this process to avoid this type of error?

Any help is appreciated - I have been stuck here for quite some time!

---

EDIT: After the very helpful answer below, here's what I implemented to fully fix my problem.  It turns out I had oversimplified a little, as r is actually a list of XML data.  So I had to deal with this in saving, and the way I did it may not be totally ideal, but so far it seems to work great:

```
savedir <- "C:\\Users\\Username\\Research\\XMLsaves"
rOutfiles <- tempfile(pattern=rep("xmlRawSaves",nChunks),tmpdir=savedir,fileext=".txt")
for (iC in 1:nChunks){
    saveXML(r[[iC]],file=rOutfiles[[iC]])
}
save(rOutfiles,searchstring,nRecords,file="repullTEST.RData")

rm(list=ls())

load("repullTEST.RData")
r <- vector("list",0)
for (iC in 1:length(rOutfiles)){
  efetch <- xmlTreeParse(rOutfiles[[iC]], useInternal = T)
  r[[iC]] = xmlRoot(efetch)  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant save the `XML` data using `save`. It looks like you parsed your `XML` data using `xmlTreeParse` with `useInternalNodes = TRUE`, `xmlParse` or the equivalent `htmlParse` etc. Your data in R is a `pointer` as you indicated in your print out. It points to an address in memory. The work here is being done by a C library `libxml`. When you close R your C program ceases and this memoery is free again. When you try to `load` the previous data you get back a set of `pointers` which now dont relate to anything and

> R has encountered a fatal error and needs to close.

What to do?  You need to save your internally represented `XML` using the package function `saveXML`.

> Methods for writing the representation of an XML tree to a string or file. Originally this was intended to be used only for DOMs (Document Object Models) stored in internal memory created via xmlTree, but methods for XMLNode, XMLInternalNode and XMLOutputStream objects (and others) allow it to be generic for different representations of the XML tree.

The reason the crash occurs only when the `XML` package is loaded is probably because when the `XML` package is loaded it tries to do something with the object you load in, the set of pointers and this causes the crash as it accesses some random memory address.

Comment: Perfect - thank you!  Fixed my problem, and I understand what I'm doing better in general.  Very much appreciate your help!